# Adding rewrite conditions to the existing ones

Tags: url-rewriting

We had out customer request to redirect their custom url to specific page  in the webshop directory, for that we setup a rewrite rule with rewrie condition as shown below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.xxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /online/index.php3?shopid=111 [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} abc.xxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /online/index.php3?shopid=111 [R]
```

As shown in above rules and condition the request coming from abc.xxx.com will be redirected to the web page in the webshop id 111 and it worked successfully

After few weeks the same customer had another request to add another URL for redirection for differn webshop ID 112
 I used the similar rewrite rule and condition replacing the new URL and webshop  id, and added it below the old rewrite condition and rules and restarted the apache but when i tested the new URL it was redirecting to shop ID 111 instead of 112.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} def.xxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /online/index.php3?shopid=112 [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} def.xxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /online/index.php3?shopid=112 [R]
```

Later I had some work around and changed the order,I put the new rewrite rules and conditions first i.e ahead of the old rules and it worked perfaclty fine.

Does anybody have idea about this characteristic of the rewrite rules?